# checking if data types are appropriate and returning an error message if not

Tags: r

I want to return my error message if arguments passed to the function are not of the required type (character)

```
if (!typeof(param1) == "character" || !typeof(param2) == "character") {
    stop("You must provide valid arguments")
  }
```

This only works if I provide invalid arguments. How can I ensure the message is displayed if some of the parameters are missing, because if doesn't work if I call the function without any parameters ?

Comment: You can use `nargs()` to test for the number of arguments to the function.

Comment: You should provide your function call at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `missing()` to check whether an argument is provided. This is very much preferred over the other answers that suggest using default values that are of a different type than what expected (how confusing!). Only use defaults when it makes sense to have a default.

Also, it is not a good idea to use `typeof()` for type checking, in general. The `typeof()` function returns how the data are stored in the R implementation. Usually, a function cares whether an object presents a particular API, which corresponds to the class. To check inheritance, use `is()`. But in this case, for both readability and just to follow conventions, consider using `is.character()`.

So you might have something like:

```
if (missing(param1) || !is.character(param1)) {
  stop("'param1' must be provided as a character vector")
}
```

Also, things to keep in mind when checking vectors:

- Often we really are expecting a scalar, i.e., a length-one vector, but a vector can have arbitrary length, so we should check that it is of length one.
- Vectors can contain missing values, which code often cannot handle, so we often need to ensure that the values are not missing.

You might find it useful to define helpers for this, such as this function from the S4Vectors package in Bioconductor:

```
isSingleString <- function (x) 
{
    is.character(x) && length(x) == 1L && !is.na(x)
}
```

Then:

```
if (missing(param1) || !isSingleString(param1)) {
  stop("param1 must be a single, non-NA string")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. To ensure not to have problms with misisng parameters, you should provide default arguments.
2. Use `stopifnot`, it is designed to check arguments.

here how I would do this:

```
func_check <- 
function(param1="",param2=""){
  stopifnot(typeof(param1) == "character",
            typeof(param2) == "character")
}

## param2 is numeric 
func_check(param1= 'a',param2=2)

## param2 is missing 
func_check(param1= 1)
```

#### EDIT

In case you want to check for missing values , toy shoudl use dotted parameters. Then you can deal it with using the `match.call`. Here an example where I test for missings and not valid parameters.

```
func_check <- 
function(...){
  ll <- as.list((match.call()[-1]))
  stopifnot(c('param1','param2' )%in% names(ll))
  param1 = ll$param1
  param2 = ll$param2
  stopifnot(typeof(param1) == "character",
            typeof(param2) == "character")
}

func_check(param1= 'a',param2=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I define the following function:

```
myfunc <- function(param1, param2, numeric1, param3) {
  if (!is.character(param1) || !is.character(param2)) {
    stop("You must provide valid arguments for param1 and param2")
  } else if(!is.numeric(numeric1)) {
    stop("Please provide numeric input")
  } else if(!is.character(param3)){
    stop("Please provide character input for param3")
  }
    #some code here for your function, e.g.
    paste0(param1, param2, numeric1, param3)
}
```

It throws an error whenever I don't give it 4 input parameters in the call of `myfunc`, including if I call it without any arguments (so the error occurs both if aguments are missing and when they are not of the correct type). Is that different from what you are looking for?

Comment: Consider using `||` instead of `|`: the `||` implies a scalar operation, which is the only thing that makes sense for the first argument to `if()`, and it only evaluates its second argument if the first is `FALSE`, which also makes sense here.

Comment: @MichaelLawrence good point, I must have mixed that up when rewriting the function to use `is.character` instead of `typeof` as the OP did in his question. I'll edit my answer.